# Windows 8.1 update deleted the original Windows 8 Wallpapers

Tags: windows-8, themes, windows-8.1

After the update from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 I realized that some images from the original Windows 8 Theme where deleted like the images below. From where can I download the original wallpaper again ? I was searching [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/personalization-gallery) but could not find what I was looking for. Windows 8 stores the wallpapers in `C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper` Does anyone else experience the same problem with the missing images after the update to Windows 8.1 ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look inside the Windows.old folder on your HDD. If you already deleted it, open the [install.wim with 7zip](http://blog.nirsoft.net/2009/09/17/how-to-extract-missing-system-files-from-the-dvd-of-windows-7vista/), go to Windows\Web\Wallpaper and extract the image you need.

Comment: I have the folder Windows.old, but where should I look in that folder ?

Comment: Thank you the wallpaper I was looking for was in 'C:\Windows.old\WINDOWS\Web\Wallpaper'